# Eliminar saltos de linea dentro de una lista, leo un archivo (nombre, numero telefonico) y debo ingresar esa informacion dentro de un diccionario

Tags: python, diccionarios

´´´
trato de meter todo dentro de un string para luego separarlo por tokens pero me une dos datos en un solo token ademas de que me imprime \n.
´´´

```
def read():
    file = open("Nombres.txt", "r")
    data = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    return data

def text(data):
    texto = ""
    for c in data:
        texto += c
    return texto

def tokens(texto):
    data = texto.split(" ")
    print(data)

#nameFile = input("Nombre del archivo: ")
tokens(text(read()))
```

Comment: Bienvenido!! Puedes por favor poner un ejemplo de como es el `.txt` de entrada y de cual es el resultado que te gustaría obtener.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour], leer [ask] y [¿Cómo crear un ejemplo verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Bienvenido! Puedes usar `file.read().splitlines()` para obtener cada línea de un .txt en una lista sin el `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas cosas que contar respecto al código que has incluido en la pregunta. Vamos por pasos:

- Tienes una función para leer el fichero. Tal como la has escrito lo que retorna es una lista, cuyos elementos serían las líneas
- Tienes una función que toma una lista de cadenas y las concatena, para convertirlo todo en una larga cadena única.
- Llamas a ambas funciones en `text(read())`, lo cual no tiene demasiado sentido. ¿Por qué partir el fichero en líneas dentro de `read()` para después volver a juntar todo en una sola cadena dentro de `text()`? Para eso mejor lees el fichero con `read()` en vez de con `readlines()`, pues de ese modo ya lo obtienes en una sola cadena, y te ahorras la llamada a `text()`
- A la hora de dividir el texto en palabras usas `.split(" ")`, pasando un espacio como parámetro. Esto funciona sólo si cada palabra está separada de la siguiente por un espacio y solo uno. Pero te dará problemas si el separador son varios espacios, o un tabulador, o un carácter invisible. Es mejor llamar a `.split()` sin parámetros para que funcione también en los casos anteriores. Además, resulta que `.split()` sin parámetros también considera el `\n` como separador, por lo que funcionará con palabras al final de la línea, y evitarás que esos `\n` aparezcan en el resultado.
- Para no tener que andar abriendo y cerrando el fichero "a mano" (es decir, usando `.close()`) se recomienda usar un *contexto* (sentencia `with`). De este modo no necesitas cerrar el fichero porque python lo hace por ti cuando el contexto finaliza.
- No necesitas pasar la opción `"r"` al abrir el archivo, ya que ese es el modo por defecto.

Juntando todo lo anterior, esta sería mi solución:

```
with open("Names.txt") as f:
  contenido = f.read()
data = contenido.split()
print(data)
```

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias! :'3
Ya implemente otra forma que se me ocurrió y quedo, pero aun así gracias por los consejos y las observaciones, los tomaré en cuenta.